# Inbuilt Permutation Generator

Tags: java, built-in

Does java have an inbuilt method to permute or randomly shuffle an Array of numbers or characters? Something like Random Shuffle STL in c++??

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(yourArray))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Collections#shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Collections.shuffle(intList);
```

If you have an array of numbers, you can use: -

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
```