# solutions for randomly mix arraynumbers in android

Tags: java, android

hi im beginner in android and need a void that get numbers in array and give these numbers randomly mix.i try to make this something like these code but this is have bugs when it arrive to near of end.any body have solution for mix randomly numbers in array,like numbers between 1 to 20?

```
rand1=randomBox();
    do {rand2=randomBox();
     }while (rand1==rand2);
    do {rand3=randomBox();
    }while (rand1==rand3 || rand2==rand3 );
    do {rand4=randomBox();
    }while (rand1==rand4 || rand2==rand4 ||rand3==rand4);
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Your approach is absolutely not leading you to what you want. Actually, I don't even understand what you want to achieve, but your do-while loops look really strange. Can you give us some example what your input is and how your output should look like?

Comment: hi i write those because site doesnt let me for ask a simple question i dont know why good questions must be long......okey this is my question:::how can i mix randomly, numbers in array?....thank you

Comment: input:{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Comment: outpu:{2,1,5,3,4,6,9,8}...this is like joke.

Comment: Your question does not need to be long. It has to be precise in a way that we understand what you want. Your question is confusing. And you should edit your answer when you add informations. Do not add it as comments. Otherwise we have to read all comments to grasp all information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(yourArray))` as explained in an other StackOverflow question: [Inbuilt Permutation Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943118/inbuilt-permutation-generator)